# Swift - Animating a rectangle

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, swift

So I have a function which runs after a delay of 3 seconds, and I wanted to know if it is possible to animate a rectangle (like a loading bar) to show progress to the user.  I looked in to the standard iOS and Xcode loading bars but it seems that you need to have a function which produces and output to increase the progress of the bar? If anyone has any ideas that would be great. The only other option is that I create one in html/javascript and run that in a web view locally - problem with that is performance won't be as good.....

Thanks

Comment: Your 'only other option' seems too convoluted. Just use a [UIProgressView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIProgressView) , you only have to call setProgress on it while the user is waiting.

Comment: @Sosdoc Ok I looked at this but never understand how to set when it should be at zero and when it would be at 100%

Comment: As the documentation says, setProgress takes a float between 0.0 and 1.0, which correspond to 0% and 100% respectively. Values in between are just percentage/100, for example: 50% = 50/100 = 0.5

Comment: Ok so how would I use this within a delay function? Is there anyway I could put something like <when function starts, set to 0> and then <when function finishes set to 1>

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have your rectangle as a `UIView`. You can animate increase in its width using `UIView.animate`. Something like this.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
        animations: {
            myView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(newWidth, myView.frame.size.width)
        },
        completion: { finished in
            if(finished) {
                // do something or just leae it as nil
            }
        }
    )
```